# Redirecting to wrong URL with Question Mark (Dreamhost)

Tags: php, .htaccess, dreamhost

**Assume:**

```
Capital = https://www.emeraldbabe.com/profile/Prabhas/347
Small = https://www.emeraldbabe.com/profile/prabhas/347
Wrong = https://www.emeraldbabe.com/profile/prabhas/347?/profile/Prabhas/347
```

I want to Redirect from `Capital` to `Small`

But when I am opening `Capital` it is redirecting to the `Wrong` URL.

Below is My Htaccess Code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]


# Redirect URLs of the form "/index.php/<URL>" to "/<URL>"
# Also handles "/index.php" only
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.emeraldbabe.com/
ErrorDocument 402 https://www.emeraldbabe.com/
ErrorDocument 501 https://www.emeraldbabe.com/
ErrorDocument 502 https://www.emeraldbabe.com/
ErrorDocument 401 https://www.emeraldbabe.com/

Redirect 301 /profile/Prabhas/347 /profile/prabhas/347
```

Comment: _"I want to Redirect from Capital to Small"_ - uh huh. And where exactly did you attempt to do that ...?

Comment: `Redirect 301 /profile/Prabhas/347 /profile/prabhas/347` - origin and target URL path exactly the same, that makes no sense.

Comment: Here is the difference between Origin URL & Target URL
*********************************************************
Origin URL has path /Prabhas/ with capital P in it
Target URL has path /prabhas/ with small p in it
######################################
Is there any way to redirect from capital to small

Comment: Right, my bad. But your Rewrite down there at the end probably does not get executed, because the rewrites at the very top will already have this rewritten to the index.php (assuming, `/profile/Prabhas/347` does not match an existing file or folder.) Try and place that Redirect directive at the very top.

Comment: I have added the redirect at the top but still, it redirects to the **Wrong** URL, and by the way why the hell **?/profile/Prabhas/347** is coming at the end of the URL. You can give it a try by opening this link https://www.emeraldbabe.com/profile/Prabhas/347

Comment: Do you mean _no_ redirect happens, or that it does redirect somewhere else entirely?

Comment: The redirect is happening but I am getting this _?/profile/Prabhas/347_  at the end of the URL. That means now my URL is `https://www.emeraldbabe.com/profile/prabhas/347?/profile/Prabhas/347`

Comment: That looks like it would come from `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`- but then the question would be, where did the `index.php` part go?

Comment: Mixing mod_rewrite and Redirect directives can often lead to unexpected results, I would to the redirect using a RewriteRule as well.

Comment: This code I have used to remove index.php from middle of the URL
`RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

Reference is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71138032/how-to-remove-index-php-from-the-middle-of-url-dreamhost

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mod_alias `Redirect` directive is conflicting with your front-controller (first rule that uses mod_rewrite). `Redirect` always works on the requested URL-path, but it is catching the query string from the rewritten URL.

You have the rules in the wrong order and you need to use mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) instead to avoid this conflict. Different Apache modules work independently and not necessarily in the order specified in the config file.

*Aside:* Redirecting all your error responses to the homepage is generally bad for SEO and users.

For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/
ErrorDocument 402 https://www.example.com/
ErrorDocument 501 https://www.example.com/
ErrorDocument 502 https://www.example.com/
ErrorDocument 401 https://www.example.com/

RewriteEngine on

# Correct case of URL
RewriteRule ^profile/Prabhas/347$ /profile/prabhas/347 [R=301,L]

# Redirect URLs of the form "/index.php/<URL>" to "/<URL>"
# Also handles "/index.php" only
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Front-controller
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Please accept/upvote the answer to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71138032/how-to-remove-index-php-from-the-middle-of-url-dreamhost - You stated that it "worked" in comments (now deleted) and you are using the same code here.

Comment: Thank you so much @MrWhite my brother you are great...
Everything is working fine now. It is resolved now...

And by the way, I will change the ErrorDocument 404, 402, etc. Since it will harm SEO I will fix it. Thanks again.

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning at this point, that specifying an absolute URL for `ErrorDocument` makes little sense in most cases (like for 404, search engine bots will not get to the a proper 404 status code any more), and that for 401 it is even absolutely wrong.